# ORDER by number of WHERE that match with MYSQL and Mongodb

Tags: mysql, mongodb

Assuming I have following mysql query:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE code='aaa' OR city='bbb' OR state='ddd' LIMIT 1
```

How can I order by number of matches of WHERE? For example, the first result should have all three conditions that match. If there is no user who has all the three conditions that match, then the first result will have two conditions that match and so on...

How to order in this way with mysql and mongodb?

Comment: can you site an example

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez I need to sort by most relevant results (more conditions are correct (the conditions 'OR'), most relevant is the result). In practice, the most relevant result is the result where all the conditions are true, if there isn't a result where all conditions are true, then the most relevant is the one where two conditions are true and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this MySQL query

```
SELECT *,((code='aaa')+(city='bbb')+(state='ddd')) count FROM `user` 
WHERE code='aaa' OR city='bbb' OR state='ddd'order by count DESC
```

if any condition `(code='aaa')` is true it will return 1

Comment: Thank you, what about mongodb?

Comment: sorry @Joy i have no idea about my mongodb